# Is there a way to use, "Extends/ Implements any Type" (say, any Serializable) as Type for Kotlin properties

Tags: kotlin

In my Jetpack compose project, I have a field that can contain different types of serializable data.

```
val httpBody : Serializable?
        get() = when(this) {
            is InitiatePayment -> this.pendingTransaction  //data class annotated with @Serializable
            is VerifyPaymentConfirmation -> this.transactionId  //Normal String
            is ValidateCart -> this.cartItems  //Another data class with @Serializable
            else -> null
        }
```

**Any?** Type works. But when using **Serializable?**,

Gives the error,

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Serializable?
Found:
PendingTransactionDTO
```

In Swift, I could just do

```
var httpBody : Codable? {
        switch self {
        case .initiatePayment(let pendingTransaction):  
            return pendingTransaction      //Codable struct
        case .verifyStoreCode(let storeCode):           
            return storeCode               //String
        case .verifyPaymentConfirmation(let transactionId): 
            return transactionId           //String
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

In this case, httpBody property accepts everything that implements the Codable interface/protocol.

In short, how to get the property type to accept any class/data class/object that is annotated with @Serializable, plus primitives like String and Int, which I suppose are by default, serializable in Kotlin.

Any tips? Or is it even possible to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the `@Serializable` annotation from the [`kotlinx.serialization` package?](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization) That's just to mark the class for processing by that library - it's unrelated to the [`Serializable` interface in Java](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable) which is the type you're using here. That annotation isn't part of the type system, so you can't use it for this kind of thing.

Depending on how you're actually *doing* the serialisation, it might be enough for you to add the `Serializable` interface type to your class definitions - like the docs for the interface say, it doesn't actually require any methods to be overridden. But if you want to, say, throw it into a `Bundle` with `putSerializable`, you'll probably have more work to do.

Comment: Good to know that there aren't any overridden methods made by the kotlinx.serialization annotation.  So there won't be any compile time checks for the type.  So just an Any type would be perfectly fine.  That could be the reason the serialization library doesn't provide a Type for this use case.

Comment: @Amal no I'm saying the *Java interface* (the type you're using here) doesn't have any methods you're required to override, so you can just apply it to something that's "supposed to be serialisable" by Java's native serialisation system (which depends on all the objects it contains being `Serializable` too). But if they can't actually be serialised *by that system* then giving them the `Serializable` type is technically incorrect. Since you're using a completely different serialization solution, it would probably be better to create your own marker interface and apply it to your valid classes

Comment: Got it. Got confused between the two.

Comment: @Amal yeah I had a look through the `kotlinx.serialization` library and I can't see anything that provides a "type" that says "this class is annotated as `@Serializable` by this library" unfortunately. You could *try* annotating your return type with `@Serializable` and see if that works! `val httpBody: @Serializable Any?` is how it usually works with type annotations - I haven't tried it with this library though

Comment: let me see if val httpBody : @Serializable Any? works. Anyway I believe Any? could be pretty fine for now since it seems to get the job done.

Comment: Also, Primitives are Serializable by default in Kotlin so need to keep that in mind too when using val httpBody : @Serializable Any?.

Answer (score 2):

Serializable is an annotation, not a type that a class inherits (unless you're talking about Java's unrelated Serializable interface), so this is not possible. Notably, the various Kotlinx Serialization libraries' `encodeTo...` functions have no restriction on the type of the argument. There is no compile-time check to make sure it is Serializable. You might as well make your function return `Any?`. The `Any?` return type is an acceptable argument for `encodeToString`, et. al.